# How to order month name starting from current month

Tags: java, sorting

Say this is the array used to store the months,

```
String months[] = {"January", "February", "March", "April",
            "May", "June", "July", "August", "September",
            "October", "November", "December"};
```

I have used this method to get the current month

```
int monthName=calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
```

What is the best way to reorder the array into a new array or arraylist starting from the current month.

Ex: The current month is August, so the desired array or Arraylist would be

```
months[] = {"August", "September", "October", "November",
            "December", "January", "February", "March", "April",
            "May", "June", "July"};
```

Comment: Check `Collections.rotate` 
[docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#rotate(java.util.List,%20int) Example [here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-util-collections-rotate-method-java-examples/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Collections.rotate. To rotate left you can use negative value of elements.

```
String months[] = {"January", "February", "March", "April",
        "May", "June", "July", "August", "September",
        "October", "November", "December"};

int monthIndex = LocalDate.now().getMonth().ordinal();//indexed from 0

Collections.rotate(Arrays.asList(months), -monthIndex); //negative value rotates to left

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(months));
```

Output: `[August, September, October, November, December, January, February, March, April, May, June, July]`

Comment: careful with `ordinal()` as this relies on internal implementation, better use `getValue()` (although, for months, I'd bet we're quite safe with `ordinal`)

Comment: @HuguesM. Yes you are right. `ordinal` comes from Enum so result depends on position of months in `Month` enum. This will work only if months will still be ordered starting from January. I used it here to have January mapped to 0 (to rotate 0 elements if it is first month) and avoid complicating code with `-1` or `+1` in while rotating.

Answer (score 6):

With Java 8's `Month.values()`, and `Collections.rotate()`:

```
int monthOffset = LocalDate.now().getMonth().getValue() - 1;
List<Month> months = Arrays.asList(Month.values());
Collections.rotate(months, -monthOffset);
System.out.println(months);
```

Prints:

```
[AUGUST, SEPTEMBER, OCTOBER, NOVEMBER, DECEMBER, JANUARY, FEBRUARY, MARCH, APRIL, MAY, JUNE, JULY]
```

Answer (score 6):

just another option for those that soon or later want to do the same using java 8 :)

```
List<Month> myMonth = Arrays.asList(Month.values());

Collections.rotate(myMonth, 1 - LocalDate.now().getMonthValue());
```

the output:

> [AUGUST, SEPTEMBER, OCTOBER, NOVEMBER, DECEMBER, JANUARY, FEBRUARY, MARCH, APRIL, MAY, JUNE, JULY]

Answer (score 1):

Because you already define the names of months in an array :

```
String months[] = {"January", "February", "March", "April",
    "May", "June", "July", "August", "September",
    "October", "November", "December"};
```

You can use a simple loop like this :

```
String[] newArray = new String[12];

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
int monthName = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int i = 0;
do {
    newArray[i] = months[(monthName + i) % 12];
    i++;
} while (i < 12);

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newArray));
```

**Output**

```
[August, September, October, November, December, January, February, March, April, May, June, July]
```

Answer (score 1):

this how could i do it

```
int pos = -1;
for(int i=0;i<months.length;i++)
  if(months[i].equals(monthName))
  {
    pos = i;
    break;
  }

String[] newOrderedMonths = new String[12];
int index = 0;
for(int i = pos ; i < months.length; i++ )
  newOrderedMonths[index++] = months[i];

for(int i = 0 ; i < pos; i++ )
  newOrderedMonths[index++] = months[i];
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
String[] newMonths = Arrays.copyOfRange(months, monthName, monthName + 12);
System.arraycopy(months, 0, newMonths, 12 - monthName, monthName);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Whole solution using Comparator.**

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * The Class Test.
 */
public class Test {

    /**
     * The main method.
     *
     * @param args the arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // First convert to List.
        String[] monthsAsArray = { "August", "September", "October", "November", "December", "January", "February",
                "March", "April", "May", "June", "July" };
        List<String> months = Arrays.asList(monthsAsArray);

        // Comparator can do a lot of the work for us...
        final Comparator<String> dateCompare = new Comparator<String>() {
            public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                Date month1 = null, month2 = null;
                try {
                    SimpleDateFormat s = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM");
                    month1 = s.parse(o1);
                    month2 = s.parse(o2);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return month1.compareTo(month2);
            }
        };
        Collections.sort(months, dateCompare);
        System.out.print(months);
    }
}
```

Comment: This returns the months in order (i.e. Jan - Dec). Or if you remove the Collections.sort, it will just print the original array.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it, use Collections.rotate.

Logic of rotation time is given, code accordingly

```
import java.util.*;

public class Rotate {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String months[] = { "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September",
                "October", "November", "December" };

        List<String> mons = Arrays.asList(months);

        System.out.println("Before : " + Arrays.toString(months));

        // September is at 9the position so rotate it 4 times, i,e 13th position, 13%12 = 1
        Collections.rotate(mons, 4);

        months = (String[]) mons.toArray();

        System.out.println("After : " + Arrays.toString(months));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Date;

public class RotateDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String months[] = {"January", "February", "March", "April",
                "May", "June", "July", "August", "September",
                "October", "November", "December"};

        Date date = new Date();
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        cal.setTime(date);
        int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);

        System.out.println(month + "Date: " + date);
        System.out.println("Original Array : " +
                Arrays.toString(months));

        Collections.rotate(Arrays.asList(months), month-2);

        System.out.println("Modified Array : " +
                Arrays.toString(months));
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to alter the input array you might have a look at this possible solution

```
public class MonthDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        String[] months = {"January", "February", "March", "April",
            "May", "June", "July", "August", "September",
            "October", "November", "December"};

        // get index of current month
        int monthIndex = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);

        // array to keep the orderen month names
        String[] monthOrdered = new String[months.length];

        // create a stream with indexes for one year start with current month
        IntStream.range(monthIndex, monthIndex + 12)
                .sequential()
                // fill the ordered array
                .forEach(i -> monthOrdered[i - monthIndex] = months[i % 12]);
        System.out.println("monthOrdered = " + Arrays.toString(monthOrdered));
    }
}
```

output (wrapped)

```
monthOrdered = [August, September, October, November, December, January, \
    February, March, April, May, June, July]
```